# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

Tags: javascript, jquery

In this line:

```
$("#id_field").append('<option value="' . data.example[x] . '">' + data.example[x] '</option>');
```

I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

in Chrome developer tool. What this mean and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.` for concatenation .In JavaScript we do it using `+`

```
$("#id_field").append('<option value="' + data.example[x] + '">' + data.example[x] + '</option>');
//                                      ^                 ^      ^                 ^
```

Comment: and is missing one `+` at the end ...

Comment: @Sirko oh yeah updated Sir .

Comment: Thanks for help. I'll mark this answer in ten minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.` to concatenate strings, which is not valid JavaScript. You must use `+`.

```
$("#id_field").append('<option value="' + data.example[x] + '">' + data.example[x] + '</option>');
```

Comment: why posting the same answer .. ?

Comment: Because when I started writing it, there was no other answer.